# Input get unfocused after every type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The input field in my component gets unfocused every time I type a char - I don't know what exactly change I did but it was working a while ago. Searching the web I found that it might be an issue with changing the input value which cause the component to re-render and lose focus. Even if that's the case - I can't find a way to work around it.

CODE:

```
handleInput = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;
    this.setState({[name]:value})
    }

render() {

const {publisher} = this.state

  return (
            {
                this.state.isEditMode ? 
                <SweetAlert 
                        title={<small>Edit mode</small>} 
                        onConfirm={this.handleEditMode}>
                    <input type='text' name='publisher' onChange={(e) => this.handleInput(e)} value={publisher}/>
                </SweetAlert> : null
            }


  }
)
```

Comment: After `this.setState({[name]:value})` try `target.focus()` in `handleInput` method - however, I would probably change the `onChange` to `onBlur` as this is a bit troublesome...different browsers handle focus differently

Comment: @DarrenSweeney nope

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or sandbox showing the issue

Comment: @DarrenSweeney well , not really - my guess that its something with `SweetAlert` component because when I move the input out of it it works. Fiddle can accept npm components?